# Collection View cell in swift get compressed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collections, view

I'm trying to display an image followed by an UILabel in collection view cell but the problem is the collection view get compressed so that only 1/4 part of the image is visible and the ui label is hidden.How i can solve this problem.I have also added the constraints for the image view inside the collection view cell but it is not working.

[Click here to see interface builder design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yovq.png)

[Click here to see the simulator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hk3P.png)

ViewControllerCode

```
import UIKit

class ShopVC: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
  
    

    @IBOutlet weak var productcollection: UICollectionView!
    var selectedpname: String!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(selectedpname!)
        productcollection.delegate = self
        productcollection.dataSource = self
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DataService.serviceobj.getProducts(product: selectedpname).count
        }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        
        if let collectioncell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectioncell", for: indexPath) as? ProductCell
        {
            let parray = DataService.serviceobj.getProducts(product: selectedpname)
            let product = parray[indexPath.row]
            
            collectioncell.updateCollectionCell(productname: product.pname, productimage: product.pimage)
            
            return collectioncell
        }
        
        
        return UICollectionViewCell()
        
    }
    


}
```

Model Code

```
import Foundation

struct Products
{
    private(set) public var pname:String
    private(set) public var pimage:String
    
    init(pname: String,pimage: String) {
        self.pname = pname
        self.pimage = pimage
    }
}
```

CollectionView cell code

```
import UIKit

class ProductCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var productname: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var productimage: UIImageView!
    
    
    override  func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        layer.shadowRadius = 5
        layer.shadowOpacity = 10
    }
    
    func updateCollectionCell(productname: String,productimage: String)
    {
        
        self.productimage.image = UIImage(named: productimage)
        self.productname.text = productname
    }
}
```

Data service code

```
import Foundation


    class DataService
    {
         static let serviceobj = DataService()
        
       private let categories = [Products(pname: "Shirts", pimage: "shirts.png"),
        Products(pname: "Hoodies", pimage: "hoodies.png"),
        Products(pname: "Hats", pimage: "hats.png"),
        Products(pname: "Digital", pimage: "digital.png")]
        
        private let shirts = [Products(pname: "Shirt1", pimage: "shirt01.jpg"),
        Products(pname: "Shirt2", pimage: "shirt02.jpg"),
        Products(pname: "Shirt3", pimage: "shirt03.jpg"),
        Products(pname: "Shirt4", pimage: "shirt04.jpg")]
    
        
        private let hoodies = [Products(pname: "Hoodie1", pimage: "hoodie01.jpg"),
                               Products(pname: "Hoodie2", pimage: "hoodie02.jpg"),
                               Products(pname: "Hoodie3", pimage: "hoodie03.jpg"),
                               Products(pname: "Hoddie4", pimage: "hoodie04.jpg")]
        
       func getCategories() -> [Products]
        {
            return categories
        }
        
        func getProducts(product: String) -> [Products]
        {
            switch product {
            case "Shirts":
                return shirts
            case "Hoodies":
                return hoodies
           
            default:
                return categories
                
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: How do your constraints look?

Comment: I gave fixed width and size to image view and pinned it to 8 from top left and right of the collection view cell

Comment: If you post some code, I'm sure one of us will be able to help you out.

Comment: Since you have a fixed height for your image view, were you able to calculate how big your cells should be?

Comment: Yes  made the collection view cell large enough to hold both image view and label

Comment: Likely an auto layout issue. You could try adding a view inside of the contentView, setting the size of that and pinning it to the cell. Then placing your views inside that.

Comment: Could you check if your collectionview is using "estimatedSize" in the size inspector? Also, are you using "flow" layout?

Comment: Yes iam using  flow layout and also I made the size as automatic

Comment: Hmm sorry, I'm drawing a blank then. If you have a repo I can look at, I'd gladly take a peak

Comment: Here is the repo link https://github.com/SaiBalaji22/CoderSwag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled your repo and took a look. It looks like you haven't set up any of the constraints in your collection view cell.

You need to set the leading, top, trailing, and bottom constraints for all your views in the cell. You also need to set a width/height constraint on your imageview and label.

[image: UIImageView constraints]
[image: UILabel constraints]
[image: Result]

Comment: Oh we should set constrains for all 4 sides in collection view cell. Thanks it works now